# how to apply multiply regex-find & replace commands on one text file?

Tags: regular-expression

I have one textfile (written in markdown) to which I want to apply a bunch of regex in order to find and replace certain structures. Can you give me a hint how to approach this issue? Can I write a probably script containing all the regex commands and apply that?

Regards

Comment: Yes, your idea about writing a script sounds correct. How to do that is however up to you as you don't show the data that you'd like to process or mention anything about what kind of processing of the data you require. Do consider adding more information to your question.

Comment: probably you can use `sed` command with `-i` option

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let's say the data is just a text manuscript and my issue are a) how do I command a search/replace regex in a script? and b) how do I apply the script to the the text file?

Comment: @paperclip You would most likely use `sed` (but not necessary).  Since you say nothing about the data or the types of transformation you want to do, this is as far as an answer would be able to go.  We can not give you a tutorial on how to use `sed` or any other text processing tools.  Please [edit] your question with further information. Do _not_ add further information that may clarify the question in comments (these are not editable/reviewable and are often not read carefully).

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream editor `sed`

#### example

`sed -e 's/search1/replace1/' -e 's/search2/replace2/'` and so on

Comment: The word "structure" in the question implies something slightly more complicated than a string.

Comment: @Kusalananda Ohkay.